# Azure Data Factory Convert Date to YYYYMMDD then to String

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm new to data factory so please bear with me.

I have files names coming in via metadata activity and I need to filter on all files that contain in the filename todays data in format YYYYMMDD

File format example: `DailyStock20200914.csv`

In my filter I have a `@contains(item().name, '20200914')` which works.

I want to add an expression something like

```
@contains(item().name, toString(toDate(utcnow(),'YYYYMMDD')))
```

but can't workout the date part and can't track down the answer on the internet.

Comment: think I may have worked this out

Comment: @contains(item().name, utcnow(yyyyMMdd))

Comment: Hi @Roger Clerkwell, Congratulations you figured it out. I help you post it as the answer,  you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congratulations you figured it out with the expression bellow:

```
@contains(item().name, utcnow(yyyyMMdd))
```

I help post it as answer and this can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.